# Xamarin iOS Push notifications do not work in Production but work fine in Development

Tags: azure, xamarin.ios, apple-push-notifications

I have a Web API hosted in Azure. The web API features a POST method and when using Postman to post with a string body message to the web API url, the message is sent to the mobile devices perfectly in **Development**. Here is the code for it:

```
[Authorize]
        [HttpPost, Route("send")]
        public async Task<NotificationOutcome> Post([FromBody]string message)
        {

            string hubName = "hubname";
            string hubNameDefaultShared = "endpointAddress";

            NotificationHubClient hub = NotificationHubClient
                            .CreateClientFromConnectionString(hubNameDefaultShared, hubName, enableTestSend: true);

            string installationId = string.Empty;

            var templateParams = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                ["messageParam"] = message
            };

            NotificationOutcome result = null;
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(installationId))
            {
                result = await hub.SendTemplateNotificationAsync(templateParams).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
            else
            {
                result = await hub.SendTemplateNotificationAsync(templateParams, "$InstallationId:{" + installationId + "}").ConfigureAwait(false);
            }

            return result;
        }
```

When I switch to **Production** and dowload the app from the store, there are no push notifications received when using Postman to post to the Web API above:

The steps I already completed:

1. App Id for both the mobile app and the Notification Service Extension.
2. Enabled Push Notifications on both and created Development SSL Push Notif certificate and Production Push Notif Certificate on the Apple Developer Website for both.
3. In my Keychain, I right clicked the "Apple Push Services: MyMobileApp" (Production) and exported the p12.
4. Upload the p12 certificate to Azure Notification Hub under APNS, and set the Notification Hub switch from Sandbox to Production.
5. Created Provisioning profiles for both Development and Productions for both the mobile app and the Notification Service Extension.
6. Edited the Entitlement.plist of both the Mobile app and the Notification Extension Service and set "aps-environment" to "production"
7. In info.plist selected the production certificate and production provisioning for each.
8. Created the ipa file and uploaded to the store.

Is there anything I have to do to the web API to set it to production regarding the notification hub? Are these all the steps to set the Notification Hub to production with the p12 certificate or have I missed something?

Answer (score 2):

I think I figured it out. What the problem seems to be is that I used my phone for testing in development mode. My phone has registered with a development device token. When downloading the app form the store in production mode, that token is no longer valid and my phone does not receive the notification. Somehow my device stayed associated with a development token even after erasing app that was installed with Visual Studio and downloading the app from the store.

I found this on the Azure documentation website link here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-push-notification-faq

**"If your hub was originally configured with an Apple sandbox certificate and then was reconfigured to use an Apple production certificate, the original device tokens are invalid. Invalid tokens cause pushes to fail. Separate your production and test environments, and use different hubs for different environments."**

So it is best practice to have two notifications hubs, one for development and another for production.